# Support size lower bound for $k$-wise uniform distribution

Tags: pr.probability

So I have this question which I can't seem to find a solution to:

> Prove that if $X = (X_1, ... X_n)$ is $k$-wise uniform* and each $X_i$ is Boolean then $\left|\operatorname{Supp}(X)\right| \geq \mathbf B(\frac{k}{2}, n)$, where $\mathbf B(r, n)$ is the number of words of weight at most $r$.

$*$ Where *$k$-wise uniform* means that, for each subset $S=\{i_1,\dots, i_s\}\subseteq [n]$ of size $s\leq k$, the distribution of $(X_{i_1},\dots,X_{i_s})$ is uniform.

Comment: Isn't the constant distribution $\delta_{1^n}$ (i.e., $X_i = 1$ a.s. for every $i\in[n]$) $k$-wise independent for every $1\leq k\leq n$?

Comment: no, it is not even 1-wise independent, k-wise independent means that if we look at a subset (every subset) of length k it will look uniform.

Comment: That's only one of the possible definitions. One of the standard ones defines it as "every subset of at most k of the variables is mutually independent". (With yours, pairwise and 2-wise do not coincide.)

Comment: For this question, I recommend using the term "k-wise uniform" instead of "k-wise independent".

Comment: @RaviBoppana and Itaysason: I have edited the OP that way, to make it clear the assumption implies uniformity.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this question was answered positively in three independent papers:

C. R. Rao (1947), "Factorial experiments derivable from combinatorial arrangements of arrays", *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society* 9:1, 128-139.

B. Chor, J. Friedman, O. Goldreich, J. Hastad, S. Rudich, and R. Smolensky (1985), "The bit extraction problem or t-resilient functions", *26th IEEE Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science*, 396-407.

N. Alon, L. Babai, and A. Itai (1986), "A fast and simple randomized algorithm for the maximal independent set problem", *Journal of Algorithms* 7:4, 567-583.